# Convert Lead into Opportunity, what does it do and is possible to do the same through Bulk API?

Tags: lead-conversion, bulk-api

I need to be able to perform a "convert" operation on multiple leads. Considering I don't know the amount of leads that will be converted, I definitely want to use Bulk API (I can end with a lot of conversions).

I wonder if there is a way to perform the conversion through the Bulk API, or even "emulate" it by creating various records with simple inserts (if this is the case, can someone tell me which records should I create and in which order, to emulate a lead conversion?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, LeadConvert method allow you to convert a list of Lead into Account/Contact/Opportunity : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_convertLead_2

Comment: Thanks. I would like to avoid apex if possible because currently we are doing everything "from the other end" (the service using salesforce API), using an apex method may actually require a lot of work (new developer required, implement an api endpoint on salesforce end and such)

Comment: According to my researches, **it's impossible** to _convert a lead_ through Bulk API, it's required to use APEX. I'll mark this as an answer because it's actually the only one possible.

Comment: OK :). So the best way is to create an apex trigger working in bulk mode and maybe add a checkbox in order to indicate to your trigger that your lead must be converted